# Open sqlite db file from a project's subfolder

Tags: sqlite, go, go-gorm

I have this folder structure:

```golang
├── gorm.sqlite // this works
├── main.go
├── simulator
│   ├── data
│   │   ├── gorm.sqlite //this does not work
│   │   └── profiles.go
│   ├── driver
│   │   ├── apis.go
│   │   ├── client.go
│   │   ├── routing-events.go
│   │   └── websocket.go
│   └── router.go
```

In my `simulator/router.go`:

```golang
func SetupConfig() {
    config := &driver.Config{}
    if db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("gorm.sqlite"), &gorm.Config{}); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else {
        config.Db = db
    }
    //etc
}
```

While `sqlite.Open("gorm.sqlite")` works and access the file in the project main folder, `sqlite.Open("/simulator/data/gorm.sqlite")` does not work! it panics `unable to open database file: no such file or directory`.
How can I access a db file in a sub folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

```
    db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("./simulator/data/gorm.sqlite"), &gorm.Config{})
```